# How can I monitor VNC via Nagios?

Tags: nagios, vnc, network-monitoring

I have a number of remote sites which have VNC running on a few computers for support purposes.  They are (obviously) only available on our internal network.

I am using Nagios to keep track of all the systems in the network and I want to have it check to make sure the VNC server is running on the appropriate hosts.

There is a 'check_vnc' plugin available [here](http://www.monitoringexchange.org/inventory/Check-Plugins/Software/Misc/Check_Vnc) but it relies on [VNC Snapshot](http://vncsnapshot.sourceforge.net/) which I don't want to use.  Certainly I could use it, but it adds more complexity and dependency, which I want to avoid.

It seems simpler to just use check_tcp to make sure I get the proper response to a connection request for VNC, e.g. port 5900, send a connect string, get back framebuffer info.  My real question, I suppose, is this:  **What is the 'proper' generic connect string for VNC (I use both UltraVNC and RealVNC) and what is the expected response?**

If it's really easier to use the VNC Snapshot and check_vnc, let me know.  I just can't imagine that a string of text isn't easier, faster, and less bandwidth intensive to monitor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for vnc:

check_tcp -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -p 5900 -w 5 -c 8 -e "RFB"

Comment: It works!  Thanks a lot.  You've save me a lot of horsing around.